# How to secure the attachment URL getting from cloud services

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-storage

I have an angular form where the user is uploading the attachment.

On uploading, the attachments are stored in the `Azure Storage Account`. In return, I am receiving the URL of the attachment.

The URL generated is accessible to the public, Is there a way how I can add my authentication?

Expected Result:

1. if a user opens the URL in the browser, it takes to `auth page`.
2. Where user will be asked to enter username - password

Comment: Yes, you can use a shared access signature token to grant temporal access to a specific file or list of files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

Comment: Is there a way I can use my own authentication above that URL?

Comment: Yes, you can. You upload the file to protected storage, so when accessed directly Azure will return a Forbidden error. Users can download the files via your API where you can check their auth status and generate a short-lived download URL with help of SAS tokens (eg: 1 minute) and redirect the user to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Shared Access Signature (SAS), I used the `generateSharedAccessSignature` method.

With that, I am using the date helper functions to easily create a SAS that expires after 1 minute.

**To be noted**: Change the access policy of the container to `Private(no anonymous access`

accountName, accountKey => get from azure. For ease and security store them in environment files

**Run the below command in terminal:**

```
npm install azure-storage
```

**NodeJS Code:**

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');

var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey);


var startDate = new Date();


var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 1);

var sharedAccessPolicy = {
    AccessPolicy: {
         Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ,
         Start: startDate,
         Expiry: expiryDate
    }
};

var token = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(containerName, blobName, sharedAccessPolicy);

var sasUrl = blobService.getUrl(containerName, blobName, token);
```

**Learning resource:**

> https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can use a shared access signature token to grant temporal access to a specific file or list of files.
But you cannot redirect to your website's "auth" page if a user open's Azure's URL.